# Instabot error, TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found

Tags: python

I tried sending a message to myself (the bot is another account), but when I run it I get this on my console:

```
import instabot
import configparser

bot = instabot.Bot()
parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
parser.read('bot.cfg')

bot.login(username=parser.get('Bot', 'email'), password=parser.get('Bot', 'password'), use_cookie=False)

bot.send_message('Hello World', ['kaminator'])
```

and when I run it, this appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\kamna\Desktop\python\instagram\bot.py", line 16, in <module>
    bot.send_message('Hello World', ['kaminator'])
  File "C:\Users\kamna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\instabot\bot\bot.py", line 863, in send_message
    return send_message(self, text, user_ids, thread_id)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kamna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\instabot\bot\bot_direct.py", line 27, in send_message
    if self.api.send_direct_item(
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kamna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\instabot\api\api.py", line 1922, in send_direct_item
    recipients = self._prepare_recipients(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kamna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\instabot\api\api.py", line 1326, in _prepare_recipients
    result = {"users": "[[{}]]".format(",".join(users))}
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found
2023-08-23 18:52:42,456 - INFO - Total requests: 43
```

Comment: your `bot.login` is not executing successfully, hence no user is there to send messages to. that's why the error. check the `bot.cfg` file, if there is any value missing or invalid